# "Title Case" in textfields using onKeyUp and RegEx

Tags: regex, extjs

I am building a web application and I want my textfields to be title case. I did my research and found that you can do the following code on the textfield's `onKeyUp` controller:

```
onTextfieldKeyup1: function(textfield, e, eOpts) {

    var str = textfield.getValue();

    var newIn =  str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });

    textfield.setValue(newIn);
}
```

This works, the first letter gets capitalized properly.

However, I also want to be able to select/highlight everything when I select/tab into the field. I know I can achieve this by doing: `selectOnFocus: true`.

The issue with the RegEx solution is that it filters *every single keystroke* so when I tab into the textview, it does not select everything, instead, it runs the RegEx and my insertion point for the text is at the end. Also, it does not allow inputs like `LeBron` or `MacArthur` as it only capitalizes the first letter and lower cases everything else.

I am using ExtJS 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check in your event if the key is not the tab key

```
    if (e.keyCode != 9) {
        var str = textfield.getValue();

        var newIn =  str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
            return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);
        });

        textfield.setValue(newIn);
    }
```

Comment: This does not select everything. I stated in the question that I wanted tabbing to highlight everything. This isn't also a good solution even if you manage to do that since you're keeping two RegEx functions instead of just fixing 1 to not trigger every time and to only capitalize the first letter.

Comment: also, the return looks something like `return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);` so that only the first character is capital, everything else isn't.

Comment: Right. This way if capital,  it won't be forced to be lower case. Good point. Changed.

Answer (score 1):

you should  listen to a different event like `change` or `blur`.

Also you can use `Ext.String.capitalize` instead of the regexp.

(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.String-method-capitalize)